Why does CBitmap::CreateCompatibleBitmap fail with error code 0?
In creating a bitmap in memory in preparation for printing, the CreateCompatibleBitmap call fails. GetLastError returns 0. I have no idea why it should.
Here is the function call that fails:
if (!m_pImageMemBitmap->CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, m_nMemDCWidth, m_nMemDCHeight))
{
    DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
    CString errorMessage;
    errorMessage.Format(_T("CreateCompatibleBitmap failed with error code %lu\n"), dwError);
    TRACE(errorMessage);
}


My understanding is that, although it is undocumented, a CBitmap cannot be larger than 4Gb. That limitation is considered here: m_nMemDCWidth is 76,500, m_nMemDCHeight is 6600, and the color depth is 8 bits for a total of 4,039,200,000 bits -- well under 4Gb.
Further, the failure is intermittent and inconsistent. Monitoring with Process Explorer does not turn up any obvious resource shortages or leaks.

I don't think GetLastError() returns error-codes for GDI operations. At least the documentation of Win32  CreateCompatibleBitmap() doesn't explicitly mention it. If you suspect size, you can try (for testing only) smaller sizes.

You're probably running out of GDI memory. See Pushing the Limits of Windows: USER and GDI Objects – Part 2 for details. And, as mentioned, most GDI-functions do not set the last error code.

Thanks for the replies. I have tried smaller bitmap sizes but the results are inconsistent. Process Explorer shows GDI handles consumed at 127 -- well below MS Outlook and others. I will follow up on the Russinovich links. Thanks again.
